# Unable to read password in java passed when invoked from perl IO stearm

Tags: perl, io, stream

We are invoking Java code from Perl using the following command:

```
 $fh = IO::Handle->new();
 open($fh,"| $command");
```

The command is: `java MyJavaClass`

In the Java code we need to prompt the user to enter a password using `System.in`.

```
while (true)
{
    switch (c = in.read())
    {
        case '\n':
            break loop;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `in.read()` returns -1, i.e end of stream.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You pass nothing into pipe you are opening. And no need for `IO::Handle` since `open()` will overwrite `$fh`. I think it should look like

```
 open(my $fh,"| $command");
 print $fh "Mypassword\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.We dont want to pass password from perl. We have some logic in java and based on that we would like to prompt user to enter the value. Looks like java is reading from the stream opened by perl. Because of this when we prompt in java (using System.in) it is not able to read because no data available in the stream opened by perl. Is there is any way to not to use the perl stream.